# How do I add an OU from the GlobalCatalog

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I can query for users with the following, but I would like to add an additional OU=Good to the search DN. Is this possible without hard coding the full path to the GC?

```
Forest myForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
GlobalCatalog cat = myForest.FindGlobalCatalog();
DirectorySearcher srch = cat.GetDirectorySearcher();
srch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=myuser))";
SearchResult result = srch.FindOne();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to get the `DirectoryEntry` for your global catalog, and then search its `.Children` property for the OU you're looking for, and then use that `DirectoryEntry` as your search root - something like (untested, don't have AD at hand to test):

```
Forest myForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
GlobalCatalog cat = myForest.FindGlobalCatalog();

DirectoryEntry deGlobal = cat.GetDirectoryEntry();

DirectoryEntry deYourOU = deGlobal.Children.Find("OU=Good");

DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(deYourOU);
```

Of course, in reality, you'd want to add some error checking ( `!= null` and so on) to your code - but that would be the basic way of getting at your OU (I hope!)